# Byebug does not pauses in controller in RSpec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, byebug

I have added `byebug` breakpoint in spec code and it pauses the code there.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "UsedCars", :type => :request do
  describe "POST /used_cars" do
    it "creates a used car ad" do  
      byebug # <- stop here  
      count = UsedCar.count
      post used_cars_path, used_car: attributes_for(:used_car)
      expect(UsedCar.count).to eq(count + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

But when I add the breakpoint in the controller-action method of the request being tested. it does not stop there. I have even tried it in the top-level before_filter for application_controller.

`app/controllers/used_car_controller.rb`

```rb
def create
   byebug # <- does not stop here
   ....
end
```

Even in the application_controller.rb

```rb
# top before_filter
before_fitler :stop
...

def stop
   byebug # does not even stop here
end
```

I am using Rails 3 with ruby 2.2.8

Comment: I'd first confirmt that this controller method is in fact called, can you replace byebug in `create` action with `raise 'foobar'` and check if you get an exception?

Comment: I have added an exception in top_level before filter in application_controller. But it does not raise exception

Comment: Ok, now you know that the callback is not called. Do the same with your controller action - is it called?

Comment: Nope. It is still not called.

Comment: You have to check your routes. Does it have `used_car` param defined?